# Excel VBA + Fill multiple Text boxes based on values in ComboBox with or without loop

Tags: excel, vba

Sir, i am trying very hard to solve this. Please help. I made many TextBoxes on user form like textbox1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 to 16. I have data for example like this 
I want to Put a name in Combobox and want to show First search result's Name in TextBox1, Age in textbox2 City in Textbox3, Then loop search same value in next cell, if Found then His name in Textbox 4, Age in Textbox5, City in Textbox 6 and so on (Maximum 4 result to be found). I am using following code but its showing only First found result in Textbox1, Textbox2 & Textbox3 but Second found result not popup in Textbox4, 5 & 6. Please help : Code is as follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    Dim a, b, c As Integer

    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

    fnd = ComboBox1.Value

    Set myRange = Sheets("Data").Range("B4:B50")
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(What:=fnd, After:=LastCell)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    Else
        GoTo NothingFound
    End If

    Set rng = FoundCell

    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & a).Text = FoundCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & b).Text = FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & c).Text = FoundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value                     
        a = a + 3
        b = b + 3
        c = c + 3

        If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Exit Sub

NothingFound:
    TextBox1.Text = "not found"
    TextBox2.Text = "not found"
    TextBox3.Text = "not found"
End Sub
```

Please help me to sort this out. I had searched hundreds of website but stuck at this point. Thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You're not fectching the next records. Here's a quick-fix of your loop:

```
    Do
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & a).Text = FoundCell.Offset(0, 0).value
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & b).Text = FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).value
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & c).Text = FoundCell.Offset(0, 2).value
        a = a + 3
        b = b + 3
        c = c + 3
        Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(What:=fnd, After:=FoundCell) ' <-- get next record
    Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstFound '<-- Stop when retrieveing again the same first record
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()`, assuming that cell "B3" has a header:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fnd As String
    Dim txtBoxOffset As Long, j As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    fnd = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    With Sheets("Data").Range("B3:B50")
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=fnd
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            For Each cell In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                For j = 1 To 3
                    Me.Controls("TextBox" & (txtBoxOffset + j)).Text = cell.Offset(, j - 1)
                Next
                txtBoxOffset = txtBoxOffset + 3
            Next
        Else
            For j = 1 To 3
                Me.Controls("TextBox" & j).Text = "not found"
            Next
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @MohdAsif, did you get through it?

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: You are welcome. And if you are concerned with the "solution length" issue, then consider that what above is _all_ the code you need, i.e. its substitutes your _entire_ code in OP